# Método con clausula @Before no se ejecuta

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit-5

estoy empezando con JUnit en Eclipse.

El problema es que no se ejecuta el método con la clausula @Before, tampoco con @BeforeClass.

Tampoco me deja añadir expected a los @Test.

¿Qué puede ser? (Estoy usando JUnit5)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias añadir pieza de tu código de como lo estas haciendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás usando Junit5, entonces estás usando la anotación equivocada. `@BeforeClass` es de Junit4, para Junit5 debes usar `@BeforeAll`. Pero además, para ambas anotaciones los métodos que anotan deben ser estáticos, y ese es otro motivo por el cual tu método `start()` no se ejecuta.

Por el otro lado, expected te dá un error, porque se utiliza para indicar y verificar que el método tirará una excepción, por lo tanto el argumento de expected tiene que ser una clase que extienda `Throwable`

Answer (score 0):

Con jupiter me funcionó `@BeforeEach` con el metodo `public void`, y `@BeforeAll` con el metodo `private static`

Comment: Te invito a que leas: [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/107347)